# Redirecting is not properly in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, admin, redirect

I have a method that has the task of redirecting the page in the admin panel from:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/
```

to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/?date__lt=2018-6-11
```

I got an information instead of page:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly
```

Here is my code:
admin.py

First version of code:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if not request.method != 'GET':
        url = '{}?date__lt={}'.format(reverse('admin:events_event_changelist'), date.today())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**code after edit**

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    q = request.GET.get('date')
    if not q:
        url = '{}?date__lt={}'.format(reverse('admin:events_event_changelist'), date.today())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Please some hint where can be a wrong code.

Comment: what does it show on teminal ? can you show the traceback

Comment: I got empty page with information and this output in teminal: `[12/Jun/2018 10:19:34] "GET /admin/events/event/?date__lt=2018-06-12 HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message your browser is showing indicates that your site is stuck in an infinite redirect loop. Looking at your condition, it is clear why:

```
if not request.method != 'GET':
```

is equivalent to

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

A redirect always results in a `GET` request, so your view will redirect again and again...

I assume what you actually want to achieve is to redirect only if there is no URL parameter. Those are stored in `request.GET`, so your condition would look like this:

```
if not request.GET:
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you check please now my edit? I would like to check if GET is empty, I mean without `date`. I change code like now is in the question and problem still exists.

Comment: You are checking for 'date', but the parameter you are setting is 'date__lt'. On a side note, instead of replacing the initial code, it would be better add the new code, because now my answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I changed question. Now with `q = request.GET.get('date__lt')` I got an error: `AttributeError at /admin/events/event/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'`

Comment: If the code you posted is your complete view, you are not returning anything if the condition does not match. You probably want to call the method from the superclass, something like `return super().changelist_view(self, request)`

Comment: I added: `return super().changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None)` on the end of method in admin.py but I got: `'EventAdmin' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'`

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to restrict the events that you display, it might be easier to override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method instead of redirecting.

```
class EventAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            # Allow superusers to see all events
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(date__lt=date.today())

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

Comment: I tried but on the top of the page (`date_hierarchy`) I need whole dates. For example on the list I need date till today. But in `date_hierarchy` I need whole dates.